# Remove capability to interact with a page

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, capabilities

I would like to remove the capability to interact with a certain page in the admin dashboard from certain users.
I mean read, edit, and whatever else. In other words, when a user visit a page (for example plugins page), it should say "you are not allowed to visit this page. Also, I would like to remove it from the menu.

Is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

### capability

Each page, there have an item in the Menu of the Back end, have a capability to see the menu item and access this page. If you remove this capability from the role of the user's, she can't see and access this page.

You can do this via plugin, like 'Members' or via custom code with the help of [`remove cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap). [A overview](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) about all capabilities and roles find you in the codex.

### menu item

If you need the access and only hide the item in the menu of the back end, you should change the menu array. This is possible via plugin, like 'Adminimize', or custom source with the help of [`remove_menu_page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/remove_menu_page) and [`remove_submenu_page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/remove_submenu_page).